# Error in "combobox" mouse click in external autoit interface

Tags: excel, vba, autoit

I'm trying to establish a mouse click in a combobox external GUI which falls in a Window.8 class. The details of the autoit parameters are in the image

[AutoIt info parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFm7M.png)

External GUI image,

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwppT.png)

Below is my code,

```
        HANWA_WINDOW_CLASS = "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.aec740_r14_ad1"
        HANWA_CTRL_COMBOBOX_Polarity = "INSTANCE:179"
        HANWA_WINTITLE = "HANWA W5000M-WFC"
        ControlID = "[" & HANWA_WINDOW_CLASS & ";" & HANWA_CTRL_COMBOBOX_Polarity & "]"
        Call mAutoIt.WinActivate(HANWA_WINTITLE)
        Call mAutoIt.ControlCommand(HANWA_WINTITLE, "", ControlID, "selectstring", "+")
```

Current Output: I'm not able to see a mouse click and rather there is no output error as well.

Expected Output: To see a mouse click which throws the menu from the combobox.

Is it possible to access a combobox which is inside a Window.8 application?

Comment: Is that autoit code? because it isn't valid vba code, you cannot put executable statements outside of a function/sub bloc.

Comment: It is autoit code written in excel-vba.

Comment: @VincentG. I have removed the Vba parts of the code. Could you please tell me if the approached logic is correct.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13334263/4157124).